# Does order matter when registering, gac-ing assemblies for COM interop?

Tags: .net, com, interop, assemblies, gac

When registering .NET assemblies for COM Interop, I do two things, currently in this order:

```
regasm /tlb:MyDll.tlb Mydll.dll

gacutil /i Mydll.dll
```

I use `regasm` to register the type library for COM and `gacutil` to install the assembly into the GAC.  Does it matter which order I do these two actions?  Also, as I make updates to my dll, do I need to un-register and re-register it, uninstall it from the gac and re-install it, both or neither?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does order matter?

No.

> Do you need to reinstall in GAC when
>   the dll has changed?

Yes.

> Do you need to re-register for COM
>   when dll has changed?

That depends.  If you added new types in your COM dll, then yes.  If you only changed a few internal things in existing types, then no.  To be safe though, always un-register and re-register.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I went through the ceremony of un-registering and re-registering as well as un-gac-ing and re-gac-ing.  The VB6 sees the new types I added, but for whatever reason, it throws an error that it can't find the types specified at runtime. Why might that be?

Comment: Typically the errors from VB6/VBA are not very informative. You can try not adding your assemblies to GAC and instead register them with regasm using the /codebase switch and see if that helps.

Comment: I've gotten `/codebase` to work for me in the past, but I still have questions as to how this is supposed to work.  I started another question that stems from this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062754/do-i-need-to-force-the-gac-to-reload-an-assembly-is-this-possible

Comment: FYI - I got everything to work again simply by saving my VB6 project and restarting the IDE.